# Need JQL query to find stories which is/was "in progress" for more than 30 days

Tags: jira, jql

I need JQL query to find stories which is/was "in progress" for more than 30 days. Basically any story if it is spending or ever spent in "in progress" more thab 30 days.

Have come up with this one below but it also catches the stories in "closed" status for more than 30 days.

issuetype = story and status was in ("IN PROGRESS") AND NOT status CHANGED AFTER -30d

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQL query.
This would give you all the Story-type tickets which are in "In Progress" status for the past 30 days.

```
issuetype = Story AND NOT status CHANGED AFTER -30d AND status="In Progress"
```